# SQLiteOpenHelper: fastest way to execute ~ 20k statements?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I'm using `SQLiteOpenHelper` in my Android app and would like to insert ~20k statements in the `onCreate` method. I can't use a prefilled database as then I'm facing problems with OnePlus devices ([SQLiteAssetHelper - problems on specific phones, e.g. OnePlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068268/sqliteassethelper-problems-on-specific-phones-e-g-oneplus)).

Now I stored my insert-statemtents in a file and use import it the following way: (`R.raw.prefilled_data` is the file containing the 20k statements).

Currently it takes ~ 6 seconds on a Nexus 5, which is not too bad, but maybe there's a way to make this even faster?

this happens inside `onCreate`

```
    try {
        insertFromFile(R.raw.prefilled_data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

.

```
    private void insertFromFile(int resourceId) throws IOException {
        // Open the resource
        InputStream insertsStream = AboalarmApp.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        BufferedReader insertReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(insertsStream));

        // Iterate through lines (assuming each insert has its own line and theres no other stuff)
        while (insertReader.ready()) {
            String insertStmt = insertReader.readLine();
            myDataBase.execSQL(insertStmt);
        }
        insertReader.close();
    }
```

Comment: "I can't use a prefilled database as then I'm facing problems with OnePlus devices ()." -- using [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)? What's the problem, specifically?

Comment: Use `Sqlite Transaction`  to make it more faster. see [Android Database Transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147440/android-database-transaction) for more help. if you use `Sqlite Transaction` then it will reduce `6 seconds` to `1 seconds` probably

Comment: Calling sqlite methods in main thread is a bad idea

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry, I forgot the link, added it now

Comment: @wilddev yeah, but putting it in the background doesn't make it faster, right?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK doesn't ```onCreate``` and ```onUpgrade``` happen in transactions? I tried adding them by myself, no difference

Comment: @swalkner: wrap `myDataBase.execSQL(insertStmt);` line in `transactions ` which will execute faster

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` are already in transactions.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK can you give an example for that? I don't think it makes a difference...

Comment: Assuming that we can't get your `SQLiteAssetHelper` problem fixed... 20K inserts in 6 seconds is already a fairly blazing-fast speed, to be honest. The only thing that I can think of to improve matters would be to [precompile an `INSERT` statement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29). However, that would increase the parsing time on your side, and so I don't know if it would be a net improvement.

Comment: The last part of this article sounds interesting: http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/03/sqlite-performance-tuning.html